# Delete Subfolders and Data But Leave Root Folders

Tags: windows, command-line

In a directory, I have about a thousand individual folders.  Is there a way to search through those subfolders and delete everything in them, but leave all of the folders at the root intact?

In other words, I have C:\Master with folders 1,2,3,4,- 1000 inside.  I'd like to delete the contents of 1,2,3,4,5... but leave those folders intact and just delete the contents, so C:\Master\1 - C:\Master\1000 would be empty but would still exist.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From command prompt:

- go to c:\Master
- Type `del *.* /s /q`

This will delete all files inside c:\Master but leave the folders alone